# CSS float layout with clear issue

Tags: html, css

I'm completely new to CSS, and confused as heck, and more or less just getting frustrated with floats, or positions, or anything like that. I'll try and explain best I can

```
DIV1                 DIV2
DIV3 DIV4       

DIV5   DIV6   DIV7   DIV8
DIV9                 
                     DIV10
```

So that's the layout i'm looking for. My trial and error's are all messed up. I have Div1:float:left;div2:float:left
div3:clear. Everything works upto that point. I want div4 to go right beside div3, and then 5,6,7,8 to clear 3 and 4 and then go all beside eachother.
Any thoughts? I would say the hell with it and do fixed positions on everything, but that's getting frustrating trying to figure out positions as well.

I've added in my code here. This has been messed, and played around with. I have height and width variables not because i need them, just playing around trying to make things fit

```
<style>

#div-1
{
    float:left;
    width:390px;
    height: 170px;

}
#div-2
{
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:450px;
}
#div-3
{
    width:80px;
    height:60px;
    clear:left;
    text-align:left;
}
#div-4
{
    border:dashed 2px;
    float:left;
}
#div-5
{
    float:left;
    top:350px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should really provide a code sample if you want help:  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Issue is my code is really all messed up since I've been playing around and trying everything i can think of to make it fit properly

Comment: if you're `clear`'ing at div3 then div4 won't go right beside it. depending on what `clear` value you're using it's not going to let you float anything right after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your grid laid out for you, you can see where I added the floats/clears:
http://codepen.io/mastastealth/pen/xyeli

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="right">2</div>

  <div class="left clear-left">3</div>
  <div class="left">4</div>

  <div class="left clear-left">5</div>
  <div class="left">6</div>
  <div class="left">7</div>
  <div class="left">8</div>

  <div class="left">9</div>
  <div class="right clear-left">10</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main { width: 800px; }

.main div { 
  background: #abc123; text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px; width: 200px; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.left { float: left; }
div.right { float: right; }

div.clear-left { clear: left; }
```

Comment: It's funny how to dif examples can work depending on how you code it. Yet i sat there for 2 hours playing and messing around not knowing and couldn't get it to work lol. Ty as well. This works perfect too

Comment: Yup, you can even get rid of clears all together if you group each row into another div and apply overflow: hidden on it! There's a lot of cool CSS tricks you'll learn over time. :)

Comment: Sure beats a table that's for sure. The only reason I'm trying CSS is for this site, and a table just limits me to where I want my data to display. I really love using CSS, just so much to learn.

Comment: @Brian has given a very nice answer. You will benefit from learning further about the [clear property](https://kolosek.com/css-clear-float/). In my research, it has been known to cause a lot of confusion. The clear property is **directly related to the float property**. It specifies if an element should be next to the floated elements or if it should move below them.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/uGRWY/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="DIV1">DIV1</div>
    <div class="DIV2">DIV2</div>
    <div class="DIV3">DIV3</div>
    <div class="DIV4">DIV4</div>
    <div class="DIV5">DIV5</div>
    <div class="DIV6">DIV6</div>
    <div class="DIV7">DIV7</div>
    <div class="DIV8">DIV8</div>
    <div class="DIV9">DIV9</div>
    <div class="DIV10">DIV10</div>
</div>
<pre>
DIV1                 DIV2
DIV3   DIV4
DIV5   DIV6   DIV7   DIV8
DIV9                 
                     DIV10
</pre>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
}
.wrap > div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 25%;
}
.wrap > div.DIV1,
.wrap > div.DIV4 {    
    width: 75%;
}
.wrap > div.DIV9 {    
    width: 100%;
}
.wrap > div.DIV10 {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: That gives me a "great" start and something to work with now. Thank you so much